# Connect to Amazon RDS Postgresql with IAM Role

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I try to give my EC2 instance access to my AWS RDS Postgresql database via IAM.

First, I've created a policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds:connect"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:824224273455:db:instance-name/db-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

After that I attached this policy to a `role`, which I attached to this specific EC2-instance. Everything seems to be fine till now.

When ssh to that specific EC2 instance and try to connect to the database, `psql` still prompts for a password.

Anyone knows how to accomplish it that I can connect without needing to use a password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RDS PostgreSQL(vanilla & Aurora) supports IAM auth now.

Supported versions are:

[Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/amazon-rds-postgresql-now-supports-iam-authentication/) (supported from 2018/09/27)

- 9.5.13 or higher
- 9.6.9 or higher
- 10.4 or higher

[Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-aurora-postgresql-supports-iam-authentication/) (supported from 2018/11/08)

- 9.6.9 or higher

Instructions are just like MySQL's:

1. create DB instance with IAM auth enabled
2. create IAM auth user with rds_iam ROLE
3. add new policy for IAM access
4. request temporary credentials for IAM auth(details https://gist.github.com/quiver/509e1a6e6b54a0148527553502e9f55d)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) is used to grant permissions for the RDS service (eg creating, backing up and deleting clusters). However, it **cannot** be used to grant login access to an Amazon RDS PostgreSQL database. Instead, use normal Users defined within PostgreSQL.

Such access [is only available](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html) for MySQL and Aurora.

Comment: Postgres is now supported.